# how to get zulu time difference seconds/milliseconds in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The excel column contains Zulu Timzezones How to calculate the difference between two dates in `seconds.milliseconds`

From Time `2022-04-25T04:16:57.823121842Z`

To Time

```
2022-04-25T04:16:58.173194593Z
2022-04-25T04:16:58.089133751Z
2022-04-25T04:16:58.462278784Z
2022-04-25T04:16:57.829376293Z
2022-04-25T04:16:57.961790312Z
2022-04-25T04:16:58.445884586Z
2022-04-25T04:16:57.830806273Z
2022-04-25T04:16:58.067723338Z
2022-04-25T04:16:58.470913276Z
2022-04-25T04:16:57.838787068Z
```

When I Try to Do something like `=B13-B14`

*Error
Function MINUS parameter 1 expects number values. But '2022-04-25T04:35:59.092943356Z' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.*

Converted to Number format

Comment: Just a small remark: you mention your times being mentioned in a particular timezone, but as you seem only to be interested in time differences, you don't need to take that timezone into account :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **REVISED: I forgot to convert the milliseconds**

You can convert the date strings into time values by breaking them into parts:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2,10)) + TIMEVALUE( MID(A2,12,8) ) --MID(A2,20,10)/24/60/60
```

Where A2 is the date string.

This assumes that they have the exact structure that you have shown and fully padded with zeros.  If that is not the case, for example the milliseconds could be .095Z, then you can mod this to:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2,10)) + TIMEVALUE( MID(A2,12,8) ) --MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"Z",""),20,999)/24/60/60
```

to be safe.